# Sharing 2nd Hard Disk Drive in Ubuntu Server 12.4

Tags: server, samba, file-sharing, sharing

Greetings to all the techies and Gurus!

I have Ubuntu Server 12.4 LTS with Samba Server Installed.  I have a 2nd 2TB HDD.  I want to Create a Folder in the 2nd HDD and share it with windows PC's.... How do I do it?
Appreciate all your help peepz.. 
Chers

Answer (score 1):

I think that this guide will be helpful for you:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20%28Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal%29%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!

The main steps from the guide:

1. Set a password for your user in Samba

   ```
   sudo smbpasswd -a <user_name>
   ```
2. Create a directory to be shared

   ```
   mkdir /home/<user_name>/<folder_name>
   ```
3. Make a backup to be safe:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/samba/smb.conf ~
   ```
4. Edit the conf file (you can use any editing program, I prefer gedit)

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
   ```

   add the following lines to the end of the file:

   ```
   [<folder_name>]
   path = /home/<user_name>/<folder_name>
   available = yes
   valid users = <user_name>
   read only = no
   browseable = yes
   public = yes
   writable = yes


   ##Note that before and after the equal sign should be a SPACE!
   ```
5. When done, restart the samba:

   ```
   sudo restart smbd
   ```
6. Once Samba has restarted, to check syntax errors, run:

   ```
   testparm
   ```
7. To access the shared directory from windows run:

   ```
   \\<HOST_IP_OR_NAME>\<folder_name>\
   ```

The folder name will be the value that you used in "" in "/etc/samba/smb.conf".

Comment: hi, thanks you for taking time for above, but what I need is to create and share folders in my secondary HDD for ex. lets say sdb5..... any Idea?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, yes, that's also possible, assuming that the partition is mounted... You will have to change path = /media/sdb5/custom
if the partition is mounted in /media/sdb5, or you can right click on the mounted drive and you can find under properties the file path...

Comment: sboda, thank you for that I manage to share the folder, I can navigate in the folder from a windows user... but the non of the windows users are unable to create/modify/save any file under the folder. I have no restricted permission set to the folder folder is set to 777... any idea where i am going wrong?

Comment: You're welcome! You should add  `write list = user_name` after  `browseable = yes`.
 (I think if you add just  `write list = *` then anyone will have acces to write it!) Please accept my answer, if this will work!

Answer (score 0):

I fingered it out. put both hard drives in the same folder when when you edit fstab. then just samba the folder with both drives you added to fstab. for instance i did mkdir /media/USB1 , and mkdir /media/USB2 . Added both in fstab.conf then just nano the smb.conf to the /media drive and both hard drives show up. so my smb.conf looks like this

[poopyshare]

```
comment = Sambapoo on Ubuntu

path = /media

read only = no

browsable = yes
```

luv ya

Comment: You do realize the question is almost 10 years old, right??